# Tag badges and the unearned badges page

Tags: discussion, badges

You can earn the [Custodian](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/227/custodian), [Reviewer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/157/reviewer), and [Steward](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/228/steward) badges for seven different review types. If you earn one such badge, then it does not appear on the [unearned badges page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=unearned), even if you don't have that badge for all review types.

The tag badges can be earned for any tag, but if you earn one, it remains on the unearned badges page. This seems inconsistent. Is this because the system sees a bronze homework badge to be different from a bronze calculus badge? Shouldn't a tag badge appear on the unearned badges page only if you are yet to earn one?

Comment: Hmm... By the same logic, I should see "Nice Answer" among the "unearned badges" page, because I can still earn one. (Nonetheless, this thread brings a valid discussion.)

Comment: How does that follow from this logic?

Comment: Thorough reading reveals I was critiquing SE logic -- the intonation was a bit off, though. Apologies for that; 't was probably due to exhaustion.